# Can't place desktop icons in the 2nd screen

Tags: windows-10, display

I set the 2nd display to be as my main display but icons are still in the default screen. How can I solve this?

Comment: Dragged them manually but I think this should be automatic

Comment: It's not, necessarily. Depending on if you've arranged icons before and other factors. Dragging the icons over manually is a relatively normal part of getting the icons on the screen you want, even after adjusting the primary monitor setting.